# Draw shadow on rectagle in java using android.graphics.Paint

Tags: java, android, graphics, shadow, drawrect

I am trying something that I assumed to be very simple: drawing a rectangle with a drop-shadow.

For text it is simple:

```
private void drawText() {
    Graphics g = game.getGraphics();
    paint.setColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 255));
    paint.setShadowLayer(5, 1, 1, Color.rgb(210, 210, 210));
    g.drawString("Sample text", 640, 300, paint);
}
```

But how to do the same for a rectangle? `g.drawRect` does not include a reference to "paint"...

Comment: how come drawRect doesn't have Paint parameter?

Comment: @pskink: That is my question exactly!